# How do I insert this code "MultipleActiveResultSets = true;" in my ConnectionString in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been getting this error

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.'

Most of the solution for this problem, `MultipleActiveResultSets = true;` are to be insert in the DataSource ConnectionString

Example:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=MSSQL1;" +   
    "Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI;" +  
    "MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
```

But mine looks like this...

```
string constr1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"]` <= this means that it is in web.config ... modify it there

Comment: The real solution is to *not* use the same connection from different threads. Multiple *client* calls won't make slow queries run faster. This error typically points to other problems, eg attemps to speed up slow queries by parallel execution, which only end up slowing things more. Or using a global connection instead of opening and closing them immediatelly. Perhaps even connection leaks?

Comment: What does your code look like ? How/why were two readers opened on the same connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change, in your web.config Or App.Config, the connection string in this way:

```
<add name="ConnectionString"  connectionString="Data Source=MSSQL1;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"/>
```

At the end of connection string simply add this `"MultipleActiveResultSets=True"`

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config file you should have a configuration for your connection string.

```
<configuration>  
    <startup>   
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />  
    </startup>  
    <connectionStrings>  
      <add name="ConnectionStringName" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False" />  
    </connectionStrings>  
</configuration>
```

If you look at the  tag, you'll see MultipleActiveResultSets=True is in there.

And then you can read it like you are already doing in the code like this.

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
```

Change the "ConnectionStringName" to the name of your connectionstring. In your case, it is just "ConnectionString"

Comment: Also, I don't think you should be adding ".ConnectionString" to the end, it should just be `var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"]` as it is pulling a string object (the connection string) from a collection (your configuration's connection strings).

Comment: No, you should definitely add it to the end, so that it picks the connection string part  of the <add name> tag... this is in the documentation. @ataraxia

Comment: Ok, well I have a fully functional ASP.NET Azure API that doesn't append this and it works fine.